# the nextflow channel join pattern

Tags: nextflow

```
 inputfq = Channel
    .of('/playground/barcode01.fastq.gz',
        '/playground/barcode02.fastq.gz',
        '/playground/barcode03.fastq.gz')
    .toList()
    .view()

params.samples_csv = "./samples.csv"

CTRL_ch = Channel
    .fromPath(params.samples_csv, checkIfExists:true)
    .splitCsv(header: true, sep: ',')
    .map { row -> tuple(row.sampleID, file(row.infq), file(row.ref)) }
    .view()
    .join(inputfq, by: [1])
    .view()
    .map { csvRow, fqFile -> tuple(csvRow[0], fqFile, csvRow[2]) }
    .view()
```

The nextflow script is listed above, and the samples.csv file is at the same directory:

```
sampleID,infq,ref
DNA_CTRL,/playground/barcode01.fastq.gz,/playground/ref/DNA_ref.fa
RNA_CTRL,/playground/barcode03.fastq.gz,/playground/ref/RNA_ref.fa
```

But only the first two .view() results showed on the screen.
So I think something wrong at the .join() step.
Can someone show me what I did wrong?

My expected results will be
[/playground/barcode01_reads_without_host.fastq.gz, /playground/barcode02_reads_without_host.fastq.gz, /playground/barcode03_reads_without_host.fastq.gz]

[DNA_CTRL, /playground/barcode01.fastq.gz, /playground/ref/DNA_ref.fa]
[RNA_CTRL, /playground/barcode03.fastq.gz, /playground/ref/RNA_ref.fa]

[DNA_CTRL, /playground/barcode01.fastq.gz, /playground/ref/DNA_ref.fa]
[RNA_CTRL, /playground/barcode03.fastq.gz, /playground/ref/RNA_ref.fa]

[DNA_CTRL, /playground/barcode01.fastq.gz, /playground/ref/DNA_ref.fa]
[RNA_CTRL, /playground/barcode03.fastq.gz, /playground/ref/RNA_ref.fa]

============================

Thank you for the reply.

Sorry for the confusion. I realized that my samples.csv didn’t match the inputfq, so I fixed it.

What I am trying to do here is part of a maneuver to ensure that the processes are executed in the order I want.
Inputfq is the output from one process, which generates many files and will always be executed. In the workflow, I have a conditional process that is executed when samples.csv is provided. The problem arises when samples.csv is provided; the process extracts information from the samples.csv and is executed prematurely, and the content of the (row.infq) in the CTRL-ch is one of the files generated in the process that creates the inputfq.
Therefore, I use .join() to orchestrate the order of the processes, ensuring that the process that generates inputfq is executed first when samples.csv is provided, and this .join() approach is acted as a verification for the existence of the two input files in the samples.csv.

I put 4 .view() for debugging, and the results indicates something went wrong at the join() step hence this post.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the docs for [join](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#join), it shows that when one queue channel is exhausted (i.e., no more objects to iterate over) it stops producing channels. So, you only showed 2 output lines because your csv has only 2 lines.

I don't understand how you are trying to join the 2 channels since there are no overlapping file names, so the `by` operator shouldn't have emitted anything since `file(row.infq)` and `inputfqs` are not the same.

Regardless, I think you are looking for [combine](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#combine). But your expected output doesn't make sense to me as it looks like the output of the two separate channels without `join`, but with `CTRL_ch` repeated 3 times.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Sorry for the confusion. I realized that my samples.csv didn’t match the inputfq, so I fixed it.